# Formal way to say "I believe"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, formality

I am writing a chapter in a book and I want to say that "I believe that this researcher is right ....", in a more formal way. Can I say "The present author believes ....."

Comment: Well, "I believe" is perfectly fine, but you can say, eg, "As this author understands the circumstances/details/facts/myths, ..."

Comment: Or, "This author is of the opinion that ..."

Comment: Saying anything other than _I believe_ implies that the author is not taking responsibility for the truth of the statement. It's not formal, it's simply dodging the issue.

Comment: This site is about the English language itself: word meanings, pronunciation, spelling, grammar, history. For advice on writing, writing styles, or academic standards, one of these other sites might be helpful: [academia.se], [writers.se], [literature.se], [workplace.se], [interpersonal.se]. If you are learning English, take a look at [ell.se]. If you want to try another site, please ask for migration, or else delete here before re-asking the question on the other site. See: [ask].

Comment: If there is an unstated specific concern, such as “What does (word) mean in context?” or “How does (grammar or punctuation rule) apply in context?” try asking that question instead. Also check out: “[Where can I ask for free proofreading? – Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7571)”.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect the question to be closed as a matter of opinion. And this answer may also have a short future, since it is writing guidance.

In academic writing, saying *I believe that this researcher is right ...* is inappropriate for multiple reasons.

- *I [whatever]* violates most academic style guides, whatever we may think of them. You should avoid writing in the first person. If you must mention yourself, use *this author/writer/researcher/commentator/etc*.
- *I believe* is redundant. You wouldn't be writing it if you didn't believe it.
- The *this researcher* part is unclear. I will assume you mean the author of the work you are discussing.
- *right* is an absolute value judgement, and should definitely be avoided unless the topic is religion or morals, or perhaps philosophy and you know what you are doing. Use phrases such as

  - *x makes a strong case that etc*
  - *x has a sound argument for etc*
  - *x supports his contention well that etc*

Since you say you are writing a book chapter I suggest you contact the intended publisher for editorial guidance.

In conclusion, the formal way to say ***I believe*** is to not say it.

Comment: A few words you could use with this approach: *Convincing*, *compelling* and *persuasive*. They all imply that the author believes the researcher, without implying that anything is definitely true.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your questions, but...

I was always told that saying anything along the lines of "I believe" is generally unnecessary because the readerknow that it is your opinion/belief as the author of the book. It's your book, so everything in it that's not a quote or attributed to another source is your thoughts.

It would only be necessary to explicitly state that you believe something if you were showing contrasting ideas.

Also, I've also been taught that saying things like "I believe..." or "I think..." or "It's my opinion..." can be viewed either as conciliatory or as weakness. Debate analysts find that debaters who avoid those phrases are seen as more confident and assertive than debaters who do use them. But if you're trying to calm people down and avoid arguments, it might be a good idea to use "softer" language.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Unfortunately, my example is not complete, because at some other points I want to say that I disagree to something.

Comment: I think it's worthwhile (no, make that "critically important") to make a distinction when you are discussing both "matters of fact" and "matters of opinion".  It may be a matter of fact that Joe Blow was born in 1947, but, *in your opinion*, his biographer played a little loose with the facts when claiming he was brought up in a one room log cabin in the north woods.

Comment: But there are other ways to state opinion without referring ton oneself or to personal belief: "Evidence suggests..."/"Some  theories state..."/"However, conflicting stories report..."/"Although the official history says ____, recently unearthed documents reveal ..."  Or toss in modals of possibility: may/might/could/can't/etc.  It may not be appropriate for every piece of writing, but for anything formal, academic, or journalistic, that's what I do.